# Need dynamically created buttons to work independently in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In Angular i have dynamically created a group of buttons that all have the same action (to show text when clicked) everything works fine yet when I click one button they all perform the action. I need them to work independently of each other. I have dynamically made a different id for each button and was wondering if there was a way to us the id to have them work independently.

Button HTML and TS files:

```
<button id="{{index}}" class="btn btn-secondary" style="float: right;" (click)="onClick()">Discription</button>

import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-discription-btn',
  templateUrl: './discription-btn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discription-btn.component.css']
})
export class DiscriptionBtnComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() btnClick = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() index!: number
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  onClick() {
    this.btnClick.emit();
    
  }

}
```

Button Parent HTML and TS files:

```
<div class="card mb-4 h-100">
        <a href="!#"><img class="card-img-top-other" src= "{{ post.link }}" /></a>
        <div class="card-body">
                <div class="small text-muted"> {{ post.created }} <app-discription-btn (btnClick) = "toggleDiscription()" [index] = index></app-discription-btn> </div>
                <h2 class="card-title h4"> {{ post.title }}  </h2>
                <div *ngIf="showDiscription">
                    <p class="card-text"> {{ post.summary }} </p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#!">Read More -></a>
                </div>
        </div>   
    </div>

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { BlogPost } from 'src/app/Post';
import { DiscriptionUiService } from 'src/app/services/discription-ui.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other-posts',
  templateUrl: './other-posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other-posts.component.css']
})
export class OtherPostsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() post! : BlogPost
  @Input() index! : number;
  showDiscription : boolean = false;
  subscription : Subscription;

  constructor(private discritpionService: DiscriptionUiService) {
    this.subscription = this.discritpionService.onToggle().subscribe((value) => (this.showDiscription = value));
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleDiscription(){
    this.discritpionService.toggleDiscription();
  }

}
```

Main HTML and TS files:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8"><app-featured-post *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index;" [post] = "post" [index] = "i"></app-featured-post></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4"><app-side-widgets></app-side-widgets></div>
      <app-other-posts *ngFor="let post of posts | myFilterPipe:filterargs; let i = index;"  [post] = "post" [index] = "i" class="col-lg-4" style="padding-top: 10px;" ></app-other-posts>
      <nav aria-label="Pagination">
        <hr class="my-0" />
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center my-4">
            <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Newer</a></li>
            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><a class="page-link" href="#!">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#!">Older</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</div>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogPostService } from 'src/app/services/blog-post.service';
import { BlogPost } from '../../Post';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  filterargs = {title: 'The Beginning'}

  posts: BlogPost[] = [];
  
  constructor(private postService: BlogPostService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => (this.posts = posts));
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be a great help. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Maybe you can `this.btnClick.emit(this.index);` and in `toggleDiscription()` get that index as param

Comment: So i passed in index as an argument and added an if statement into toggleDiscription() but i may have done somthing wrong

Comment: `toggleDiscription(i: any){
    console.log(i);
    if(this.index = i){
    this.discritpionService.toggleDiscription();}` @robert

Comment: Figured it out. Had to take method out of the service and put it directly into each component. When i was calling the same method from the service it was doing it to every button.